# ERROR:pinax-images 4.0.1 has requirement pillow>=7.1.2, but you'll have pillow 5.0.0 which is incompatible

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, pinax

this error occured when i was trying to install the requirements.txt from  the pinax-project-blog app.

also what is meant by `you'll have pillow 5.0.0 which is incompatible`.

```
pinax-images 4.0.1 has requirement pillow>=7.1.2, but you'll have pillow 5.0.0 which is incompatible.
```

Answer (score 2):

You should first uninstall the old version and then reinstall the latest version, note that you need two `=` signs when specifying the version of pip packages.

```
pip install pillow==7.1.2
```

The old package will be removed automatically by pip.

Comment: Or simply `pip install -U pillow` to allow upgrades.